# What is the proper way to call function outside scope in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that generates a URL.  I want to use it inside of `ng-href`.  This is all fine, until I had to move the method outside of `$scope`.  That doesn't work any more.

See this plunker example:

**EDIT** New Plunker example with comments:

https://plnkr.co/edit/z4txeXD1J2PJCfcBNw5C?p=preview

Old link: <strike>https://plnkr.co/edit/qb9w6A5nCNet2MCynnGH?p=preview</strike>

I can get it to work with some hacks, such as putting the method in the root scope (as in the example), but that's really unwieldy.  Is there a better way to "import" methods into scope?

Comment: what do you mean by "I had to move the method outside of `$scope`?  This feels like an XY problem;  neither your question or the linked code you provided really describes what you are trying to do;  they show you trying some possible "fixes" for an undetermined problem, and none of the fixes are recommended ways to deal with angular at all.

Comment: Your plunk references a script.js file that you didn't include in your plunk

Comment: @Claies hm... sorry I was unclear.

In the plnkr link, `$scope.getUrlInScope` used to be my method.  It worked.  Now I want to move this method to outside of the controller (as in, I want to move it to become `getUrlGlobalScope`).  My second `<a>` tag demonstrates that once I move the function out, the `ng-href` wouldn't work any more by just changing the function name (as expected).  The 3rd and 4th `<a>` are ways I found that works, but I feel like they're not ideal, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @jbrown yes the script.js got deleted - I moved it to the html since I thought that'd be clearer.  It shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: I edited the plunker link to have comments to clarify what I mean.

Comment: what's wrong with `$scope.functionInScope = getUrlGlobalScope;` in the controller, and not using `$rootScope`?

Comment: for that matter, why would you even need to use `ng-href` at all instead of a normal `href` if the link is generated from another library anyway?  How did the other library get the data to the HTML without angular?

Comment: Nothing wrong with functionInScope method you suggest.  I was just wondering whether that's the recommended approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why you seem a bit combative about the why.  This is a natural evolution of code.  But if you must understand, I first started with `href`.  Later, I wanted to generate a link that has variables from scope, so it became like `ng-href="my_link?q={{query}}"`.  Later yet, that logic is replicated everywhere, so I made it a function, so `ng-href="{{genLink(query)}}"`.  And finally, it turns out another part of my code wants to call this method (in node.js), so I want to put it into its own file, hence the question.

Comment: The other method I can think of to map a non-angular function into angular would involve creating a service that gets injected into your controller, but that seems like it's a bit much for what you are describing.

Comment: and I don't mean to be combative;  it's just rather common that angular questions asking for how to do things outside angular involve people not understanding a feature angular has, and it's hard to give the "angular way" if you don't know what the end goal is.  In your case, what you are describing seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful enough.  I will look into service - it may actually fit my need.  In practice it's not just one method I want to move, so a service may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `directive` that does the URL generation and creates a `ng-href` (or even creates an anchor `<a>`)

Comment: I thought about this, but it seems a big change to the code when I just need something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass in the $window for the variables you need from outside, and instead just use $scope as you would normally in angular inside the ng-href?
    ng="{}" using the single curly braces in angular refers to expresssions.

```
  <a ng-href="query">$scope.query</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    function getUrlGlobalScope(q) {
      return 'some_url_global?q=' + q;
    }

    (function(angular) {
      'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.getUrlRootScope = getUrlGlobalScope;
      })
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope','$window', function($scope,$window) {
        $scope.getUrlInScope = function(q) { return 'some_url?q=' + q; }


        $scope.query = 'query';
```